# How to use two database systems (MongoDB/Postgres) for storing different data in a website

Tags: database, mongodb, postgresql, couchdb

I am building a website which will contain profiles in a stackoverflow fashion (generally speaking), where I first need to have a Postgres DB for all the relational data and then I need to have tags as a feature, for example a user should have their own descritptive tags such as "php,wordpress" etc.

I am thinking to store all the taglist in a non-relational database such as Mongo or Couch and then pass the related queries to fetch them into the profile.

But how would the profile database (postgres) or the model (MVC) know what tags to fetch for each profile?

I am not asking for code, only architecturally-wise, how would that be possible, from a top-down, higher perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use from **CQRS** and if you use the best architecture for your project, The **DDD (Domain Driven Design)** concept is very useful